# Key not found in key ring: AspNetCore.DataProtection usage between Asp.Net IIS application and .Net Core Windows service/console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, iis

**Problem**

I have an IIS application built with ASP.NET (.NET Core 3.1) that is protecting data using AspNetCore.DataProtection, and passing that protected data to a Windows service/console application built with .NET Core 3.1, which performs an Unprotect, both installed on the same instance of Windows 10 on the same PC.  However, the .NET Core application is unable to find the correct key to perform the Unprotect.

Specific error when attempting to Unprotect:  'The key {GUID} was not found in the key ring.'

**DataProtection 'Protect' implementation in IIS application**

In Startup.cs

```
services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\TestLocation\"))
        .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(36500));

services.AddSingleton(DataProtectionProvider.Create("TestApplication"));
```

In controller constructor

```
dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("TestApplicationProtector");
```

**DataProtection 'Unprotect' implementation in .NET Core console/service application**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddDataProtection()
        .DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration()
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\TestLocation\"))
        .SetApplicationName("TestApplication");

var providerService = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var providerProtection = providerService.GetDataProtectionProvider();

dataProtector = providerProtection.CreateProtector("TestApplicationProtector");


// within a method in the class
// generates the error mentioned above
var unprotectedData = dataProtector.Unprotect(protectedData);
```

The key is created and persisted to the file system by the IIS application, but during unprotect in the console/service application, DataProtection is trying to find a different key ID that does not exist, and therefore cannot perform the Unprotect.  Essentially the key IDs are different.

What am I missing that is causing the 2 applications to generate/use keys with different IDs?

Something to note is that for the ASP.NET IIS application I am using the built-in DataProtection library, and with the console/service .NET Core application I am using it as a package from Nuget.

Comment: Why these applications use different dataprotection lib? What about ASP.NET IIS application using nuget lib?